# UI tool for monitoring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

I'm looking for any available open source monitoring tool for Kafka. I'm on Kafka 0.10.0. Apparently, some open source tools like yahoo kafka-manager and kafka-web-console are not compatible. Just wondering if there are any other tools available which works with the latest version.

Comment: Really good question. I had the same question. Does kafka provide something out of the box?

Comment: https://medium.com/@giorgosmyrianthous/overview-of-ui-monitoring-tools-for-apache-kafka-clusters-9ca516c165bd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also use kafka 0.10.0, yahoo kafka-manager actually can work, u just need to pull the one with this PR: https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/pull/282

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I'm going to pull the patch and rebuild the app. Just wondering, is there any change in the configuration file to make this work ? Once we build the app from source, we had to update the config file with zookeeper entry. Is it still the same ?

Comment: no additional changes need to be made, just follow the `README.md`, it will worked. we use ENV `ZK_HOSTS ` to connect to the zookeeper. This gem also provide authentication which is very useful regarding security concernings

Comment: Thanks,it worked as you said. I could create the cluster and view the topic, partitions, and replicas. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow you to look into the messages. Just curious, are you aware of any tools which allow you to do so?

Comment: Not sure, we did not use kafka/zookeeper anymore, since it is hard to maintain and scale, we use nsq instead which is easier to hook up and scale.

Comment: @Shamik To view messages in a topic - you can use [kafka-topics-ui](http://kafka-topics-ui.landoop.com/)

Comment: @AntoniosChalkiopoulos ... Thanks a ton, exactly what I'm looking for. I'll take a deeper look into the landoop suite, thanks for sharing.

Comment: <br/>
Gafka also a good free gui application<br/>
https://isurujayakantha.github.io/gafka-releases/